# Is there a way to replace the rasterizer with my own code?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

I understand that the graphics pipeline runs as so:

[image]

But I want it to run like this:

[image]

Any suggestions? Is this possible?

Comment: It's not possible but also not needed.  What ever you thought you were going to do in "custom rasterizer" can go into either the geometry shader or the fragment shader instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: Sort of.

You can't control the rasterization process with custom code, but you can control the final pixels to be rasterized. Control of the rasterization process amounts to culling pixels you don't want to appear through various modes.

Here's what you can control, paraphrased from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_1/ns-d3d11_1-cd3d11_rasterizer_desc1) (The principles are the same between DirectX and OpenGL/Vulkan)

- Fill modes: How much of the interior of a triangle should be rasterized.

  - Solid: Show the entire triangle filled in with color.
  - Wireframe: Show only the wireframe of the triangle.
- Cull Mode: Which face of the triangle should be removed from rasterization.

  - None: Show both sides; don't cull anything.
  - Back: Don't show the back.
  - Front: Don't show the front.
  - Both: Don't show the triangle at all. (This is rare, usually done though other means)
- Winding order: Determine the front of the triangle given a vertex order direction.

  - Clockwise: The front is determined by a clockwise winding order.
  - Counterclockwise: The front is determined by a counterclockwise order.
- Scissors: Allow clipping entire regions at once.

  - Enable/Disable: Actual scissor regions are defined through the viewport.
- DepthBias: How much to move verticies that are overlapping to prevent Z fighting.

  - Enable/Disable
  - Clamp: Maximum value by how much to alter the depth value.
- SlopeScaledDepthBias: Primarily used for shadow buffers.
- DepthClip: Clip pixels that are too far away.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could I simply do BOTH in the CullMode, then just implement my own version somehow? Also, for the purposes of my program could I simply disable rasterization altogether and simply run a shader over each pixel of the screen? I want to not waste computation time on rasterization as it isn’t useful to what I am doing.

Comment: @BradenYonano: Maybe you should describe what you actually want to do. If your application is not rasterization driven, why not go for computer shader?

Comment: @BradenYonano No. As shown in your diagram, the rasterization process happens before the pixel shader. By enabling culling on both sides of a triangle, everything is culled and therefore, those pixels are skipped, never to be sent to the pixel shader in the first place. What you describe may be related to the compute shaders, but you don't mention that, just that you "don't want to waste time using calculating something you aren't using." As BDL suggests, clarifying your question with what you are actually trying to do would help.

Comment: @BradenYonano In fact, CULL_MODE_BOTH (CULL_FRONT_AND_BACK) only exists in OpenGL and has to be implemented manually in DIrectX.

Comment: @Casey Yes sorry for not clarifying. I am wanting to essentially replace the rasterizer with a raycaster. The reason I wanted to use OpenGL or another API like Vulkan was for the nice memory management that they either do for you or relatively easily allow you to do. Essentially I didn't want to have to write a whole new driver and API for raycasting, I'd rather be able to modify an existing API instead.

Comment: @BradenYonano Okay, that makes more sense. This is a good question for how the rasterizer works, but is the wrong question to ask about ray casting/tracing. Asking a separate question via google along the lines of: "How does a ray caster work?"; "How does ray tracing work?"; and, "What is the difference between ray casting and ray tracing?" would net you better results.

Comment: @Casey I think I have a decent understanding of how raycasters work, I have written one on shadertoy, the only thing that I would be missing is how to implement that into the graphics pipeline of an API. I understand that the shaders on shadertoy are just pixel shaders with OpenGL, but I just want to know if its possible to skip the rasterization altogether and run a shader over each pixel without rasterizing first.

Comment: @BradenYonano Nope. Not how the pipeline works. Either you utilize the graphics pipeline intending to output to the pixel shader or you use the Compute Shader that does require using the rendering pipeline (but can generate input to the RP).

Comment: @BradenYonano Correction, the compute shader *doesn't require using the rendering pipeline.

Comment: @Casey That’s unfortunate. So either I basically make my own graphics card, or use a compute shader which will have poorer performance.